# Yii2 array of objects, find the one

Tags: php, arrays, object, yii2

I have an array in yii2, and ocassionally it's only 1 single object that is not empty (all other element of array is empty) and I don't know which one is it. How can I either find the one that is not empty, or (my idea what I was trying), to create a new array, with array_filter (but I'm not sure if it works also with array of objects), to have only the one object in it.

```
if (count($ttepk) == 1) {
    $ttep_filtered[] = array_filter($ttepk);
    $id = $ttep_filtered[0]->id;
    }
```

But it was also not working. I get the error message: `PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException Trying to get property of non-object`. 
Before array_filter it looks like this:

```
Array
    (
    [3] => app\models\Model Object
        (
```

after array_filter:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [3] => app\models\Model Object
                (
```

So it seems, array_filter is not the one I need, or I use it the wrong way.
Can you please help me? Thank you!

Comment: what does it mean "empty object"?

Comment: please show us what you tried

Comment: So you have one array element (`count($ttepk) == 1`). But there is not object. Try `reset($array)['id']`. But better create array var_dump, because i don't understand what is inside this array. Or you can use `is_object` to check current array value.

Comment: there is an array, all elements are empty, except one, and that one is an object (always an object, a model instance).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
$filtered = array_filter($ttepk, function($item) {
    return $item instanceof app\models\Model;
});

if (count($filtered) == 1) {
    $id = reset($filtered)->id;
}
```

Comment: i I do this: `$filtered = array_filter($ttepk, function($item) {
    return $item instanceof app\models\Model;
});` I get an empty array.